# How to get premmision to access android phone camera under Debain

Tags: android, linux, camera, debian

```
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x7e0a0] Cannot open video device /dev/video0: Permission denied
/dev/video0: Permission denied
```

I am getting this error message when I am trying to list video formats supported by phone camera using ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video0
```

or

```
root@localhost:/dev# v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Failed to open /dev/video0: Permission denied
```

Is there any way to change access premissions for /dev/video0 and /dev/video1?

Comment: You need root access on the device.

Comment: I have root access  root@localhost:/

Comment: Not root on your computer, root on the phone.

Comment: I have rooted my phone with https://www.kingoapp.com/ app . I am using DropBear for ssh and I am using GNUroot Debian from Play Store as Linux terminal on the phone